# VS2022 - Issue with tooltip on region

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have an annoying issue with Visual Studio 2022: everytime I hover on a region, a tooltip is displayed, but not loaded correctly. This issues stop VS working completely.
This is how It looks like:

[image: Issue tooltip on region]

On Task Manager I have this situation:
[image: TM image]

Actually the only workaround is to kill the process and restart VS. Is there a way to fix up this problem?

NOTE: I'm using Visual Studio 2022 64bit - v.17.4.2 on Windows 11 (10.0.22000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by disabling the [SQL Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Mojtabakaviani.SqlTools&ssr=false#review-details) extension. After that, I noticed that there is a related [issue](https://github.com/mojtabakaviani/sqltools/issues/7) on the GitHub extension repository.

Comment: Thanks! I also have SQL Tools extension. Disabled it, now it's all ok.

Comment: Thank you... Solved mine too.  

Answer (score 1):

You could try to update VS2022 to the latest available release (17.4.3), but checking the [release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#17.4.3) there isn't anything about "region" or "tooltip".

You can try to disable the VS extensions, if you have some of them installed.

At last, you could report the problem using the [dedicated web page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report?port=1025&fsid=e64c0683-87be-4676-b71b-e1dc2396a91a).

Comment: It's really a VS extension: SQL Tools. Thanks